# Can indexer events be queued to run later in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, indexing

I noticed that Magento CE 1.7 uses indexer events to process things like product saves etc. These events are stored in a table index_event and index_process_event.

Now, my situation is the following. I have a product import script that inserts between 1 and 10.000 products directly in the DB. This is very fast and much better that using the Magento API in my case.

As a safety measure, I mark all indexes as needing reindexing afterwards. This works fine, but if you're importing only 10 products, it's a bit overkill. A full reindex will take forever.

Basically I'd like to queue the indexer events and process them with cron asynchronously after the import, but I don't know if this is possible especially since it would need to be asynchronously and using cron (I don't want to block the UI).

I'd first like to understand the steps involved and then go from there to find the best solution.

As a quick-and-dirty solution I thought about creating my own queue table and run $product->save() on each product - but that may also have it's pitfalls.

Update: I found this extension which seams to use a queue as well, but my original question remains. Can this be done on a regular Magento install? http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/performance-optimization/magento-asynchronous-cache.html

Comment: I turn all indexes off by setting them to manual index apart from stock as this is the one I care about the most that must be correct on the site to the user at all times. I then run a cron job once a night on all of the indexes so everything else gets updated. This speeds up the API tremendously. We have 8000 products in our database with 3 websites and 10 stores. We do roughly 10,000 api calls a day to keep our data in sync with all of our sales channels. If I need to force an individual index on a product, I enable the indexes, save the product in admin, and then disable them again.